# T-SQL lock resouce in an event of concurrent access

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, concurrency, sqltransaction

I want to lock a certain table in the event of concurrent access.

Inside a stored procedure:

- I truncate a table
- Do calculations and populate the above table
- After returning from PROCEDURE, do a select from the table

To avoid issues in event of concurrent access, I am planning to add a 'BEGIN TRANSACTION' followed by 'BEGIN TRY -END TRY' and 'BEGIN CATCH - END CATCH'. I 'COMMIT' just before 'END-TRY' and 'ROLLBACK' inside the 'CATCH'.

Will this alone resolve all concurrency issues or I need to do something more.

Many thanks,
Sujit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could lock entire table during a transaction using `TABLOCK` or `TABLOCKX` ([references](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx)):

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

-- For shared locking:    
-- This will take a S(shared) lock at table level for duration of transaction
-- SELECT TOP(0) * FROM dbo.MyTable WITH(TABLOCK,HOLDLOCK)
-- HOLDLOCK hint is needed in this case because 
-- default behavior at default transaction isolation level (READ COMMITTED) 
-- is to maintain a S lock only during record reading.

-- For exclusive locking:    
-- This will take a (x)X(clusive) lock at table level for duration of transaction
SELECT TOP(0) * FROM dbo.MyTable WITH(TABLOCKX)

ROLLBACK;
```

Example (SQL Profiler output):

[image]

Note: `SELECT OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.MyTable')` = `1316199739`

Comment: Dear Bogdan, thanks for your advice. Another solution I received from my manager was to make use of 'LoggedInUser' field in the same table and do DML specific to currently 'LoggedInUser' to avoid concurrency issues.

Comment: @sujimon: Maybe if you give me more details about your problem I could help you more. At this moment I don't see any information regarding `LoggedInUser` column within your question.

Comment: I think I didn't put across my question correctly. I was better off without any database lock on table. I just wanted to resolve concurrency issues in multi-user environment. Which I later found can be done by A> Identify logged user profile B> Identify the computer-name accessing the application C> Use a table variable inside stored-procedure. But I agree with you regarding Table locks so I will mark this as answer !